# Toast inside of AsyncTask inside of fragment causes crashes

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

when these two Toasts are inside of AsyncTask inside of the fragment it causes crashes,  when i remove the two Toasts, everything works with no crashes.  why is this?  and how can i use toast messages inside my AsyncTask without causing crashes?

```
 Toast.makeText(activity, "onPostExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Toast.makeText(activity,"onPreExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Logcat shows nullPointerException for the toast messages. when i remove the first of the two toasts it will run then crash later, when the first toast is there it will crash on start,  when both toasts are removed it never crashes.

the rest of the code

```
 public class FragmentStaticFragment extends Fragment {

private Button buttonStartProgress;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
Activity activity = getActivity();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_static_fragment, container, false);

    buttonStartProgress = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
     progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


    buttonStartProgress.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new BackgroundAsyncTask().execute();
            buttonStartProgress.setClickable(false);
           }

        });


    return view;
}

 public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

    int myProgress;

     @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               // commented out this toast to avoid crashing
      // Toast.makeText(activity, "onPostExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       buttonStartProgress.setClickable(true);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              // commented out this toast to avoid crashing
     //  Toast.makeText(activity,"onPreExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       myProgress = 0;
      }

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       while(myProgress<100){
        myProgress++;
        publishProgress(myProgress);
           SystemClock.sleep(100);
       }
       return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
      }


} // end BackgroundAsyncTask

 }
```

EDIT;

added stack trace info

```
07-13 09:23:01.383: E/AndroidRuntime(19489): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 09:23:01.383: E/AndroidRuntime(19489): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 09:23:01.383: E/AndroidRuntime(19489):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
07-13 09:23:01.383: E/AndroidRuntime(19489):    at Android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:233)
07-13 09:23:01.383: E/AndroidRuntime(19489):    at com.example.asynctaskprogressbarexample.FragmentStaticFragment$BackgroundAsyncTask.onPreExecute(FragmentStaticFragment.java:62)
07-13 09:23:01.383: E/AndroidRuntime(19489):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
07-13 09:23:01.383: E/AndroidRuntime(19489):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
07-13 09:23:01.383: E/AndroidRuntime(19489):    at com.example.asynctaskprogressbarexample.FragmentStaticFragment$1.onClick(FragmentStaticFragment.java:36)
```

Comment: Post the logcat trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getActivity()` will return `null` if run before `onAttach(Activity)`. Instead, you should call `getActivity()` directly in your `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods or get a reference to it in `onAttach`:

```
public void onAttach (Activity attachedActivity) {
    activity = attachedActivity;
}
```

Comment: it works now,  your answer is correct, but the example you gave below the answer using onAttach did not work. and continued to crash.  but i did what you said in the answer, i put a call for getActivity in the onPreExecute method and put that into an activity variable that is a member of the AsyncTask class.  now everything works perfectly

Comment: Didn't work because by the time your toast was being created onAttach was not even been called yet, you should read about Fragment's life cycle, that would help you alot with further issues...

Comment: To further @ianhanniballake's response.  Create a global variable `private Activity mActivity;` then in the `onPreExecute` within the AsyncTask, define the variable, `mActivity = getActivity();` (for a Fragment type). `mActivity = this;` for an Activity.  Then when you call your toast, replace your `getActivity()` with `mActivity`.  there you go.